# Exclude certain words while including other patterns in regex

Tags: regex, swift

I have this string:

```
<a href="..">..</a></td><a href="Example.pdf">Example.pdf</a>
```

I would like to get all the links and I do so with this regular expression:

```
href=\"([^/]*?)\"
```

However, I would like the regular expression to ignore this specific string:

```
..
```

How would I modify my regular expression to achieve this exclusion?

Comment: [Don't parese HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839). What is your programming language? (See the usage description of the `regex` tag)

Comment: I'm using Swift. I'm not trying to parse HTML - just capture a specific pattern.

Comment: Whether to parse, extract, find, or otherwise interpret, ...that advise stands. I added the tag for you ;-)

Comment: Use `let pattern = "href=\"(?!\\.{2}\")([^\"]*)\""`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew aka `/prince of the regexp/g` is back ;)

Answer (score 0):

This one based on a negative lookahead should work : `<a.+?href=["'](?!\.\.)([^"']+)["'].*?>(.+?)<\/a>`

Use Group 1 to extract link of each match

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zym09k/1)